# How to install Gnome 3.4 (not 3.6) in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: installation, gnome, versions

Whenever I install Gnome from software center I get Gnome version 3.6 but I want to install gnome 3.4 as all my extensions and themes work on it. How to do it? Would I get Gnome 3.4 if I install from software center in Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://www.noobslab.com/2012/04/install-gnome-shell-34-and-extensions.html , I think this is what you're looking for (if not, be more explicit)